# Get time 24 hours / 1 day before current time using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

To get the current time in UTC format, I can use

```
moment.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Now, in Moment.js, how do I get the time in the same format but 24 hours before that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
moment.utc().subtract(1,"day").format("YYYY,MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

or

```
moment.utc().subtract(24,"hours").format("YYYY,MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

use `subtract` to do it.

```
moment().subtract(24, 'hours').utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```